# django digital ocean gunicorn logfiles creating a 502

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am going nuts here, I am trying to get django logging to work, which led me to need to check the gunicorn logs which I found were not setup and when i try to set them up via the config file it throws a 502 and I don't know how to track it down...

according to this... https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-django-one-click-install-image

the config file on the DO deployment is at... /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py

now when I go to that file and add a line like this as per the gunicorn docs tell me to do in the config file, and then I restart gunicorn it throws a 502 at me...

"""gunicorn WSGI server configuration."""
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from os import environ

```
def max_workers():
    return cpu_count() * 2 + 1

max_requests = 1000
worker_class = 'gevent'
workers = max_workers()
#my added config
errorlog = '/var/log/gunicorn/error.log'
```

Interesting to note is that when I srestart gunicorn with

```
sudo service gunicorn restart
```

it goes smoothly the first time and then if I try to restart it again it gives me this...

```
stop: Unknown instance: 
gunicorn start/running, process 30943
```

I have tried contacting digital ocean about this and so far they have not been helpful, any ideas of where to go next?

Comment: It was because the logfiles were not permissioned correctly I guess? I changed the permissions to 777 for both the directory and the logfiles and then it worked, What should the permissions be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was cause by the permissions of the log files for some reason. Through some more testing I have found that the log files need to be already in place, and their permissions need to be set to no less than 666.

I have no idea why they need to be this high...